# Can not call hook in template file in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have problem with call Wordpress hook in template file in my theme.

I create a demo.php file in my theme.

My demo.php file:

```
/*
    Template Name: Demo page
*/
add_action( 'wp_head', 'demo_function' );

function demo_function () {

    echo 'Hook is called';

}
```

Then I create page in Wordpress backend and select this template.
I have checked but function is not called.

I tried other WP hooks. They are same. So Any solution call hook in template file ?

Comment: You should be calling this from your **functions.php** file.

Comment: you should call this function in your function.php file